# Access array and object created by meteor autoform

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I'm trying to access info in an array created by `meteor auto-form`. The set in question is below.

```
 PlayersSchema = new SimpleSchema({

   contacts: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
  },

    "contacts.$": {
    type: Object
  },


  "contacts.$.comments": {
    type: String,
    label: "Comments From Salesmen"
  }

});
```

I need to make it to the comments in the last block but I'm not having any luck.
When you access the first part contacts it returns `object Object` which is to be expected. But when I try to go deeper and reach the comments section I have no luck. I've tried `contacts.comments` - and `contacts.comments[0]` and nothing happens.

Here's a screenshot of my console showing the placement of the comment i need to reach

[Console Array Comment Placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PvRF.png)

Once I reach the comments I want to place them in the template I have below. Like I said I can get `object Object` to show in this form, but nothing else.

```
<template name="showPerson">
  {{#with person}}
  <h1>Show Person Details: {{name}}</h1>
  <div class="row">

      Comments: {{contacts.comments}}

  </div>
  {{/with}}
  {{> update}}
</template>
```

New to javascript and meteor so please forgive my ignorance!!

Comment: can you add your helper for returning the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also loop through contacts:

```
{{#each contacts}}
    {{comments}} <!-- this might also need a loop -->
{{/each}}
```

If Contacts is a different collection, make sure you have a helper to return a cursor in order to loop

Comment: The problem is a loop returns all Comments. What I would really like is the option to pick and chose which Comments are displayed, returning all into the template will not work for my needs.

Comment: I know it's possible to chose the returned items, but the syntax for it is a little confusing to me.

Comment: @AlexFerraro then simply write a helper to return one comment OR multiple comments if you want a loop. findOne() for returning one object.